# Is it possible to control the rotation of a material with a normal map?

Tags: shaders, normals

Why does the normal map change the rotation of the reflection? The texture is set to be Non-color.[image]

Is it possible to keep the bump of the normal but have the reflection be perfectly straight?
[image]

Comment: All that a normal map does is to change the angle-- rotate-- the reflection.  There may be some issues, but talking about them would require seeing the normal map, the material nodes, the mesh, and the UV map used.  A link to a file would probably be the best way to share that, but pics might be sufficient.